# Camera2 API - Why the same surface needs to be specified twice?

Tags: android, android-camera2

Looking at Camera2 API, it appears that a surface needs to be specified twice. Once it is done during `createCaptureSession`, passing in the list of surfaces. At a later point, we once again specify the same surface to the preview-builder's `addTarget` method. If we are going to specify the target surfaces later, why do we need to specify the list of surfaces initially during `createCaptureSession` call? What does `addTarget` really do with the surface that `createCaptureSession` is not doing? Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the capture session, you need to list all the Surfaces you might want to use for your requests.  This allows the camera device to configure its hardware processing pipelines to be able to provide all those outputs at the requested sizes and for the requested destinations (such as 1080p preview to SurfaceView/TextureView, full-resolution JPEGs to ImageReaders, 4K video recording buffers to MediaRecorder, and so on)

Then each request includes a subset (or all) of those Surfaces.  Not every request will generally want to include every configured Surface; you'd usually only include the full-resolution JPEG ImageReader Surface for snapshots, and only include the MediaRecorder Surface when actively recording video.

If the Surfaces were only included in the capture requests, then the camera pipeline would have to reconfigure itself on the fly when it sees a new Surface that hasn't been used before.  This generally causes a 300-600 ms pause as the camera hardware flushes out its data and reconfigures itself.

So to ensure smooth operation, the camera2 API requires the application to specify all the desired outputs for the current session up front.

Comment: Thank you very much for the perfect answer. Is there any overhead of adding a surface but not really using it all the time? For example, ImageReader gets used only if a user requests a snapshot.

Comment: If you need it for your use case, have it in your session. You could only create a session with an ImageReader when the user hits the shutter button, but that adds a bunch of latency to image capture.  Usually that's undesirable.   But yes, each Surface uses up resources in some way - turning on different bits of the processing pipeline, using larger resolutions from the sensor, etc.  So don't add them if they're not used at all.